# pandas.Series groupby pct_change with no filling missing values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, vectorization

How can one compute `pandas.Series` `groupby` `pct_change` in a **vectorized way** with no filling missing values?

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
d = pd.Series(data=list(range(1,6))*2,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],range(0,5)]), dtype=np.float64)
d.loc[(slice(None),2)] = np.nan
d.groupby(level=0).pct_change(fill_method=None)
#     filled = getattr(self, fill_method)(limit=limit)
# TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

I understand that I can just use `apply`:

```py
d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(fill_method=None))
```

and **I am looking for a more efficient solution**.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `d.groupby(level=0).pct_change(fill_method=None)` ?

Comment: workaround: `d.unstack().diff(axis=1).stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: @JuanC `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string`

Comment: @anky The result is wrong. Compare the output of your solution to `d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(fill_method=None))`

Comment: It seems `d / d.groupby(level=0).shift() - 1` does the trick. Thank you, everybody!